# $location.path() isn't working after facebook login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook

I have this controller:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $location){
$scope.fbLogin = function() {
openFB.login(
    function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            console.log('Facebook login succeeded');
        } else {
            alert('Facebook login failed');
        }
    },
    {scope: 'email,publish_actions,user_friends'});
};
console.log(openFB.getLoginStatus() == 'connected');
if(openFB.getLoginStatus() == 'connected'){
$location.path("profile").replace();
$location.reload(true);
}
})
```

After a successful login I want to redirect to the profile page, but this doesn't work unless I reload the page manually.

What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using an external library, you need to tell angular when that library triggers events that you want your app to react to. Angular relies on a constant "[digest loop](https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/)" - this is where the magic happens. Most of the time angular handles things without you knowing, which means that bugs like these are hard not to miss sometimes!

The good news is it should be pretty easy to fix, just wrap the code that triggers on the event into a function and pass it to `$scope.$apply()`:

```
if(openFB.getLoginStatus() == 'connected'){ 
  $scope.$apply( function() { 
    $location.path("/profile").replace();
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

After seeing your comments, it's clear this isn't an angular issue - it's your logic. You want to change the location once the facebook login has completed, but you're not running the code in the callback. What you need to do is make sure that you change the location of the page after the login response has been received:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $location){ 
  $scope.fbLogin = function() { 
    openFB.login( function(response) { 
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // This runs on success 
        $scope.$apply( function () { $location.path('profile').replace() } ); 
      } else { 
        alert('Facebook login failed'); 
      } 
    }, {scope: 'email,publish_actions,user_friends'}
    ); 
  }; 

  // This runs when the controller is instatiated, i.e. only once when
  // the page loads. At this point you have no response from FB
  if(openFB.getLoginStatus() == 'connected'){ 
    $location.path("profile").replace();  
  } 
})
```

Note that you still need the code that runs immediately (the bottom section) for the case that the user is already logged in to Facebook when the page loads.

Finally, for sake of argument, I'll show you an option **that you shouldn't use**, but that is useful to know for other occasions:

```
$scope.$watch( openFB.getLoginStatus , function (value) {
  if (value === "connected") {
    $location.path("profile").replace();
  }
);
```

What the above does is watches  the result of the first function you pass, then calls the second argument as a callback when it changes. This happens every time angular runs a digest loop, so as long as you make sure that you call `$scope.$apply()` in the callback for `openFB.login()` this will run, and everything will work.

The reason you should not use this approach is that (I imagine) the `openFB.getLoginStatus` function is not particularly simple, and may even involve HTTP requests - functions that you pass to `$watch` should always be fast and simple to ensure that your app performs well.

Comment: It didn't worked as I expected. I still need to press F5 to reload in order to go in the profile page. I will be very glad if you can show me the process with the states and changing the state after loading.

Comment: Pressing f5 will completely reload the page so must be running some different code. Does the console ever output `true`? Is there anything else in the console?

Comment: well this executes before the connection so the first thing is- false, after that Facebook login successful and if I press F5 it gives me true and changes the location

Comment: Thank you for the help. It's still not working as expected. But I thing the problem is from the .states. Now I have this:

( // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/menu2/login'); ) 

And it doesn't want to redirect me even on refresh. When I change it with this:

( // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/menu/profile'); )

It redirect me but it doesn't open me the login page by default. I have to go by myself. If you can help me with that I will be more than happy :)

Comment: It hard to see without a working plunker or more of your code. I also think it's outside the scope of this question, so perhaps open another.

Comment: Okay, Thanks anyway :) You helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Angular $location documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

You should consider using `$location.url(<url to go to>)`

So in your case `$location.url("/profile");` should do the trick. The `url` method on `$location` is a getter and setter, so will let you set the URL without reloading the page.